# Python pandas merge keyerror

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas, merge

Consistently getting a keyerror when I try to merge two data frames. The code:

```
c = pd.merge(a, b, on='video_id', how='left')
```

Based on internet research I double checked the dtype and coerced both to int:

```
a = pd.read_csv(filename, index_col=False, dtype={'video_id': np.int64}, low_memory=False)
b = pd.read_csv(videoinfo, index_col=False, dtype={'video_id': np.int64})
```

Renamed the columns (to make sure they match):

```
a.columns.values[2] = "video_id"
b.columns.values[0] = "video_id"
```

Coerced to df:

```
c = pd.merge(pd.DataFrame(a), pd.DataFrame(b), on='video_id', how='left')
```

Out of ideas as to why I'm still getting the keyerror. And it's always "KeyError: 'video_id'"

Comment: You should post a sample of your original data to reproduce your problem.

Answer (score 25):

You want to be careful not to use `df.columns.values` to rename columns. Doing so screws with the indexing on your column names.

If you know which column names you're replacing, you can try something like this:

```
a.rename(columns={'old_col_name':'video_id'}, inplace = True)
b.rename(columns={'old_col_name':'video_id'}, inplace = True)
```

If you don't know the column names ahead of time, you can try:

```
col_names_a = a.columns
col_names_a[index] = 'video_id'
a.columns = col_names_a
```

Keep in mind, you actually don't need to use the same column names on both dataframes.  Pandas allows you to specify the individual names in each dataframe

```
pd.merge(a, b, left_on = 'a_col', right_on = 'b_col', how = 'left')
```

Answer (score 3):

There was a leading space in one of the dfs in the column name, `'video_id '` instead of `'video_id'`. Not sure why the initial rename didn't fix that but it's fixed.

Answer (score 3):

Sending the left_on and Right_on parameters as arrays worked for me.

```
c = pd.merge(pd.DataFrame(a), pd.DataFrame(b), left_on=['video_id'], 
             right_on= ['video_id'], how='left')
```