# Issues merging DataFrames

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have two dataframes I am trying to merge. I created these DataFrames by grouping them.

Here is a copy of the code I used to create the data frame:

```
subdomain_wt_mx = links_webtrends_mx[['SubDomain','Page']].groupby(['SubDomain']).agg(['count'])

subdomain_aa_mx =Mexico[['SubDomain','Page URL']].groupby(['SubDomain']).agg(['count'])
```

When I try to merge them , I get the error below:

```
Common_Domain_Mx = subdomain_wt_mx.merge(subdomain_aa_mx,on=['SubDomain'])
```

I get a :

> Key Error

Can someone please advise on how to solve this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python pandas merge keyerror](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34227038/python-pandas-merge-keyerror)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use

```
Common_Domain_Mx = subdomain_wt_mx.merge(subdomain_aa_mx,on = 'SubDomain')
```

Comment: Same issue. Get Key Error

Comment: Can you post output of subdomain_wt_mx.columns and subdomain_aa_mx.columns?

Comment: I have updated it with the code. Please review it to see if you can figure out whats wrong

Comment: The dataframe you get from after grouping is multi-index so you need to do subdomain_wt_mx = links_webtrends_mx[['SubDomain','Page']].groupby(['SubDomain']).agg(['count']).reset_index(). If it doesn't work after that, pl post the links_webtrends_mx.head() after reset_index