# I got 'key error 4' error message when merging 2 dataframes

Tags: python, dataframe, merge, keyerror

I tried to merge 2 dataframes, but got error message "key error 4".
The code I tried is:

```
A = df1['A']
B = df1['B']
C = df2['C']
D = df2['D']

df1.merge(df2, left_on = [A,B], right_on = [C,D],how='left')

KeyError: 4
```

Comment: Have you checked [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34227038/python-pandas-merge-keyerror)?

Comment: Use just the column names for the left_on and righ_on parametes like this:  `df1.merge(df2, left_on=['A','B'], right_on=['C','D'], how='left')`  You don't need to assign the columns to those variables.

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead:

```
df1.merge(df2, left_on=['A','B'], right_on=['C','D'], how='left')
```

Note: I am just using the string column headings in the left_on and right_on parameters.