# python pandas merge missing columns from right dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, merge

I encountered a problem just like this [Python pandas merge keyerror](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34227038/python-pandas-merge-keyerror) but none of the solutions worked for me. I assume some of the code isn't relevant but I just included it just in case. I basically want to calculate some gradients on some of the rows from one column and join it back to the original dataframe

```
import numpy as np
from scipy import signal

df = item_loc_df_dict['key_name']
prob_series = df['col1'].astype(float).values[5:(len(df['col1']) - 5)]
week_series = df['date_col'].values[5:(len(df['date_col']) - 5)]

gradient = np.square(np.gradient(prob_series))
win = signal.windows.hann(8)
gradients = signal.convolve(gradient, win, mode='same') / sum(win)
grad_df = pd.DataFrame({'date_col': week_series, 'peak_grads': gradients})

gradient_mean = np.mean(gradients)
gradient_std = np.std(gradients)
min_height = gradient_mean + gradient_std
peak_indices = signal.find_peaks(gradients, height=min_height)[0]
peak_grad_df = grad_df.iloc[peak_indices].reset_index(drop=True)

peak_grad_df['date_col'] = peak_grad_df['date_col'].astype('datetime64[ns]')
df['date_col'] = df['date_col'].astype('datetime64[ns]')

joined_df = df.merge(peak_grad_df, left_on=['date_col'], right_on=['date_col'], how='left')
joined_df['peak_grads'].fillna(0, inplace=True)
```

I would get `KeyError: peak_grads` on the last line, so the merge wasn't including the column from my right dataframe. The left dataframe `df` has about 200 columns, so I tried adding

`df = df[['date_col', 'col2', 'col3']]`

to the top of my code, and then the `KeyError` went away and my merge worked as expected. Why does this merge only work when I reduce the number of columns from my left dataframe?

Comment: I would take a look at what the dataframes look like before and after merge. My initial guess is that you have a "peak_grads" column in both which, when you merge, would create "peak_grads_x" and "peak_grads_y" columns. When you subset your dataframe, you remove the problematic column

Answer (score 1):

Use suffixes parameter or print columns (joined_df.columns) to test @christina Stebbins hypothesis

```
joined_df = df.merge(peak_grad_df, left_on=['date_col'], right_on=['date_col'], how='left', suffixes=(False, False)))
```

This must raise "ValueError: columns overlap but no suffix specified: Index(['peak_grads']"